# About Prime Generation in "C" - What is wrong with my code ? -

Tags: c, math, computer-science

I'm a third year irregular CS student and ,i just realized that i have to start coding.

I passed my coding classes with lower bound grades so that i haven't a good background in coding&programming.

I'm trying to write a code that generates prime numbers between given upper and lower bounds. Not knowing C well, enforce me to write a rough code then go over it to solve. I can easily set up the logic for intended function but i probably create a wrong algorithm through several different ways.

Here I share my last code, i intend to calculate that when a number gives remainder Zero , it should be it self and 1 , so that count==2;  What is wrong with my implementation and with my solution generating style?  I hope you will warm me up to programming world, i couldn't find enough motivation and courage to get deep into programming.

Stdio and Math.h is İncluded

```
int primegen(int down,int up)
{   
    int divisor,candidate,count=0,k;

    for(candidate=down;candidate<=up;candidate++)
    {
        for(divisor=1;divisor<=candidate;divisor++)
        {
            k=(candidate%divisor);
        }
        if (k==0) count++;
        if(count==2)
        {
            printf("%d\n", candidate);
            count=0;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    primegen(3,15);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `third year CS student and i have to start coding` What?

Comment: @Falmarri - Definitely a WTF moment there. :-)

Comment: a third year CS student but he does not have to start writing.

Comment: I just took C programming and MIT Simply Scheme ; C was 1.00 over 4 ; Scheme was 2.50/4

Comment: Please do not get laugh on me :) I have to be encouraged.

Comment: @alorsoncode, If you need to be encouraged to write code, then maybe you should reconsider your career. For example, my girlfriend feels that I need to be **discouraged** from writing code.

Comment: "i couldn't find enough motivation and courage to get deep into programming" - In general, Computer Science contains a lot of programming.  Further, it requires a lot of self-motivation to learn, a lot of self-teaching; as the ever-changing technology world continues to adapt, you, as a computer scientist, must adapt as well.  I'm not saying you're in the wrong field by any means, but I am saying that if you're going to stay in Computer Science, you need to get used to programming and motivating yourself to perpetually learn more about programming.  Best of luck to you!

Comment: Encouraged? Honestly, you should be **discouraged** at this point. This is coming from a 3rd year CS student? If you're so disinterested in writing code I can't possibly see you being successful in CS.

Comment: Heh - reminds me of one of my old-school (in more ways than one) professors way back when, whose opinion was that Computer Science was a branch of mathematics, and that writing actual programs belonged to the Electrical Engineering discipline, not sullying up his syllabus.

Comment: guys, I know what he is saying is unuasal (CS student who doesn't like coding) but you do know that CS is much much more than coding yeah? I hope coding is not the main thing they taught you in your CS degree.

Comment: Thanks for all comments, but i have to say something about this issue; if you discouraged from a course in METU ( Turkey ) you should have a strong mental power to get rid of this unusual case. I faced with different and unpleasant personal cases, so that i can make a restart to my career and my remaining life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int primegen(unsigned int down,unsigned int up)
{   
int *ar;
int divisor,candidate,count=0,k;

for(candidate=up;candidate>=down;candidate--)
    {   count=0; 
        for(divisor=2;divisor<candidate;divisor++)
            {if (((candidate%divisor)==0)) count++; }
            if(count==0) {printf("%d\n",candidate); count=0;}

    }
}
int main()
{
primegen(3,15);
return 0;
}
```

Finally i have corrected my solution. The main problem was that i weren't assigning count to zero before the second for loop. I changed the order of candidate (big to small) and i corrected little syntax mistakes.

Thanks all you for your encouraging help and answers. :) I'm happy to have this done , so i can pass through other algorithms&problems.

Answer (score 3):

You're including 1 and the `candidate` in your `candidate%divisor` tests, both of which will always return 0, so every number you test will appear prime.

Instead of this:

```
for(divisor=1;divisor<=candidate;divisor++)
```

do this:

```
for(divisor=2;divisor<candidate;divisor++)
```

#### update

There are too many things wrong with your code to list, but here are a couple anyways:

- you're checking the result of `candidate%divisor` outside the for loop
- by the time you check `k`, `k` is always `candidate%candidate`, or 0
- you only ever check `k` once, after the divisor loop
- don't `continue` at the end of your loop, that's what happens by default

Look, here is some pseudo-code for the simplest possible implementation. Try to find where your code deviates from this:

```
for candidate = down to up
  // assume the candidate is primt
  prime = true

  // check all divisors from 2 to the candidate - 1, inclusive
  for divisor = 2 to candidate - 1
    if candidate % divisor == 0
      // divisor is a factor of candidate
      // candidate isn't prime, so we can stop checking
      prime = false
      break
    end if
  next divisor

  // if prime is still true, we successfully tested every number from 2..candidate
  // and found no factors
  if prime
    print "candidate {candidate} is prime!"
  end if
next candidate
```

Comment: Thanks for the psuedocode , your first suggestion doesn't make difference in execution .  :(                                                  If you extend your proposal for the "for" loops i hope i can understand easily. Sorry for acting as dummy :)

Answer (score 2):

- In your inner loop you calculate `candidate%divisor` for all divisors, but only after the loop is finished you check if `count` should be incremented. So you only increment it only once per candidate, for the last divisor checked.
- Also you do not reset `count` for each candidate in the outer loop. So you count the found divisors for all candidates together while you want to count for each candidate individually.

Comment: I now realized that ; for example 6 code tries 1,2 then count==2 so that consider 6 as prime. I try to overcome this problem but i forgot a much of C to struggle with such problems. I'm keeping trying. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints to keep in mind

```
if(!(candidate & 0x01))
    // We know its even so we can stop

if(candidate == potential_factor)
    // We can stop

if(candidate % potential_factor == 0)
    // The potential factor IS a factor and we can stop
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , but i don't know first notation? Why it's hexadecimal?

Comment: I think, first condition checks the evenness then its 2k, so that it cannot be prime. Am I right (correctly understood?)

Comment: it checks if the the "one's bit" is not set. if you don't have a 2^0 you can only be even.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has reformatted the code for clarity from its original submitted form.  In doing so, they've modified one of the three mistakes in the code.

The first mistake was that the second for statement did not have brackets after it.  As a result, the loop body consisted only of the statement which followed the second for statement.  From reading the code, it's clear that the questioner intended everything after the second loop statement to be executed repeatedly.  This is not what was happening.

Essentially, the idea was: for each number in the range, try all numbers between 1 and the candidate.  Count the number of those which divide it.  See if there are exactly 2.  This is a correct algorithm and the answer which say to not divide by 2 is wrong.

However, the implementation was doing this: for each number in range, divide the candidate by every number between 1 and the candidate.  Then, once you've done all that division, check to see if the last one came out even and if so, add 1 to the count.  So, what's happening is that you're only actually checking to see if `candidate % candidate == 0` which it always does.

The second mistake, is that the count is only reset when it gets to 2.  So, what's happening is that the code, for any input, will return every other number.  For each candidate, `count++` happens exactly once.  So it reaches 2 and gets reset every other time.

The third mistake is that once the inner-most loop is fixed, then the continue will do the wrong thing since it only continues the inner-most loop.

Comment: Thank you for serious analysing code, i'm trying to reduce syntax mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I know your code is for educational purposes only, however you should consider Sieve of Eratosthenes as it would probably be the fastest algorithm for your problem. What it basically does is:

1. At first consider all numbers prime numbers.
2. Starting off with 2, you consider all the multiples of a prime number non-prime.
3. Go to the next prime number and make all it's multiples non-prime.

I think you would get a better understanding of the algorithm by reading this: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

As for the implementation, just use an array which has all it's elements set to zero, and set the elements from prime number to prime number to one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This has been exceeding my expectations, it's a good algorithm , so when i succeed my first algo , then i will get deep into your method.

Comment: By the way i just try to get used to write basic algorithms to get warmed up C programming. Before today , i have wrote a lot of different codes , but insufficient exercising, i forgot a lot of them...